# Possible to make generic function to find a particular item with Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to make a generic function to find a particular item?

I do this C# code (Src : [Use Explicit Waits in Selenium WebDriver Correctly](http://endanwang.blogspot.fr/2012/02/use-explicit-waits-in-selenium.html))

```
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.Url = "http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading";
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
        {
            try
            {
                return d.FindElement(By.Id("someDynamicElement"));
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        });
```

I would replace wait.Until((....); using a generic function.

How can Ideclare a generic *By* selector to find a particular item?

Here is a list of the built-in Selenium2 selectors:

```
ClassName
CssSelector
Id
LinkText
PartialLinkText
Name
TagName
XPath
```

For example :

```
IWebElement myDynamicElement = WaitForElement(????) // for exemple By.TagName = "Test"
public static IWebElement WaitForElement(**By selector**)
{
    wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
    {
            try
            {
                return d.FindElement(**By selector**);
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static IWebElement WaitForElement(IWebDriver driver, By selector)
{    
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    return wait.Until<IWebElement>(d =>
    {
            try
            {
                return d.FindElement(selector);
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
    });
}
```

This would be called with something like:

```
WaitForElement(driver, By.Id("someDynamicElement"));
```

You just give it an instance of a `By` selector. The underlying `d.FindElement` call will then deal with the rest, it will deal with figuring out what 'kind' of selector it is. You don't need to do much.

The whole concept behind the `By` class, is to make it generic in the first place. You will be duplicating work.

You will also have to pass in the `driver` as well, unless you plan to have it as a `static` field or an extension method on the `driver` itself.

Comment: Thank's for your help Arran. It's OK.